# why my OOP methods doesn't print in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, oop

```
class Item:
    def calculate_total_price(self, x, y)
        return x * y

        item1 = item()
        item1.name = "Biscuit"
        item1.price = 6000
        item.quantity = 2
        print(item1.calculate_total_price(item1.price, item1.quantity)
```

why my method doesnt print? still new on learning OOP following the instructor but still wont print

Comment: you have to unindent everything after `return x * y`, otherwise it is part of the method and never gets called

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools article:

> A return statement is used to end the execution of the function call and “returns” the result (value of the expression following the return keyword) to the caller.

So when you write the return statement the function will end, so everything you do after it won't execute.

You can simply save it to a variable like this:

```
multiple = x * y
```

Read more about return statement in this article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/

Comment: Why are you quoting C language documentation in a question about Python?

Comment: Because it's the same logic. Anyway you're right, I edited my response.